# Swift - Trying to set up a share button

Tags: swift

I'm trying to set up a share button from a time I previously coded it. I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what. Can you help? This is on a different view controller than the main one.

```
import UIKit

class MoreViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBAction func shareKnockingBuddy(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let messageToSend = "Here is a message. \(doorsKnocked)"

    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [messageToSend], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }


}
```

Here's my error: On the App delegate it's "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". On the message thingy on the bottom, it says "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController shareKnockingBuddy:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe282c02eb0'
*** First throw call stack:"

Answer (score 0):

Notice the error is about UIViewController and not your MoreViewController class. This means you did not set th proper class name for the view controller in your storyboard. Change it to MoreViewController.

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain you're right. I'm pretty new to this, but how do I make sure I've set class correctly? I thought I already did, but maybe I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: Here is where I set the class originally. http://imgur.com/a/ZJnex Do I need to set it somewhere else as well? I made it as a Swift file and not a cocoa file, could that be the problem?

Comment: That should be it. Now that it's set, you might need to reconnect the actions.

Comment: I tried reconnecting the actions and it still didn't work. Here is the error it keeps giving me. http://imgur.com/a/xXm4T  I'm really confused.

Comment: It's the same error which means you haven't fixed the view controller yet.